# (Organic Chemistry) Common Atoms in Organic Molecules

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecules, atoms

What are 6 atoms commonly found in organic molecules?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your question? If you provide more context, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon, Hydrogen, Nitrogen, Oxygen, Phosphorus, and Sulfur. Best way to remember this is CHNOPS.

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/The_six_most_common_elements_in_organic_molecules_are